# how to summerize data base on two filter?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried to summerize the amount by code and year, but I got an error, what I miss?
[image: this what I tried to do, but without success]

[image: second try using summerize]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you trying to do I think this might can help :

Solution proposed with a subset of your data :

[image]

Go to Modeling then create a New table with this code :

[image]

```
SummarizedTable = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(Tab;Tab[date];Tab[code]);
    "CA"; CALCULATE(SUM(Tab[amount]))
    )
```

Result :

[image]